# Does chart_Series() work with logarithmic axis?

Tags: r, quantmod

Is there a way to produce logarithmic y-axis with `chart_Series()`? I am using the experimental `chart_Series()` rather than the `chartSeries()` method in `quantmod`, because it is more convenient when adding additional lines to the plot.

```
library(quantmod)
POWR <- getSymbols("POWR", auto.assign=FALSE)

# the following attempts did not produce logarithmic axis for y
chart_Series(POWR, log.scale=TRUE)  # like in chartSeries()
chart_Series(POWR, log="y")         # like in plot.default()
```

From a quick look into the code, it does not seem to be possible using existing `chart_pars()` or `chart_theme()` methods for customization, too.

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: I'm trying to port some existing `chartSeries` code and am stuck on this functionality. has anyone found a way to log scale the axes? plotting the log of the underlying values is not a viable solution

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need an OHLC chart and the Close is all you need you can use the `chart.TimeSeries`function from the 'PerformanceAnalytics' - package, where you have lots of options to customize the chart.

```
chart.TimeSeries(cumprod(1+ ROC(POWR, type = "discrete")[-1,6]),ylog = TRUE,minor.ticks =FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your extra arguments don't work because they aren't expected as passthrough parameters (via `...`) to any function inside `chart_Series`.  If you simply want log candles, try
    `chart_Series(log(POWR))`